# Grouping by a date produces incorrect results

Tags: crystal-reports

Using Crystal reports 2013 (version 14.1.x)

I have created a report with three layers of grouping:  employee name, work date, detail id.  Each group is sorted in ascending order.  The report identifies changes to reported employee time.

Employee name and the column headers are in the page header.

Group headers and footers are intended to be blank in the final product, but contain info now for testing.

My "Details" section shows work date and a bunch of other data.

The work date group is not working.

After adding work date to the work date group and to the detail id group, I see a work date group for 3/21/2021 that has a range of work dates in the detail id group (and, therefore, also in the details).

This UI seems pretty straightforward.  Is there some well-known Crystal issue you gurus have seen hundreds of time that I am missing?  Or some common Crystal magic (like grouping on the date cast to a string in yyyy-mm-dd format) to resolve this?

My group by expert looks like...

```
@EmployeeName - A
    Command.WorkDate - A
        Command.DetailID - A
```

...and the output looks like...

```
             Work Date    Type      Hours
Begin Employee:  Joe Smith
  Begin Work Date:  3/21/2021
    Begin DetailID:  Work Date:  3/21/2021
       Was:  3/21/2021    regular    8
       Is:   3/21/2021    vacation   8
    End DetailID:  Work Date:  3/21/2021
    Begin DetailID:  Work Date:  3/21/2021
       Was:  3/21/2021    travel     2
       Is:   3/21/2021    vacation   2
    End DetailID:  Work Date:  3/21/2021
    Begin DetailID:  Work Date:  3/24/2021
       Was:  3/24/2021    overtime   2
       Is:   3/24/2021    regular    2
    End DetailID:  Work Date:  3/24/2021
  End Work Date:  3/21/2021
End Employee
```

Why am I not seeing only 3/21/2021 data within the 3/21/2021 group?

Answer (score 0):

For groups based on date fields, Crystal Reports provides an additional option.

```
This section will be printed:
  for each day.
  for each week.
  for each two weeks.
  for each half month.
  for each month.
  for each quarter.
  for each half year.
  for each year.
  for each second.
  for each minute.
  for each hour.
  for AM/PM.
```

The default value is `for each week.`  In order to group by day, select `for each day.`